# Looking for a function which is convex when x is between 0 and 1 but concave when x is greater than 1

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am looking for such a function for plotting a figure like in the picture in Python.

Many thanks!

[image]

Comment: What is Python? Are you sure it is the right site?

Comment: @markvs Python is an interpreted programming language, with an impressive suite of functions and objects for mathematical computation. We even have a [tag:python] tag for this site.

Comment: @Linghui You could try experimenting with shifting $\arctan(x)$ or $\frac{x}{|x| + 1}$ vertically and horizontally.

Comment: @TheoBendit: The OP wants users of Math. SE to write a piece of code for him? What is the context in this question?

Comment: @markvs Leaving the (highly dubious) quality of this question out of it, I think the OP wants to use python to produce a graph, which they are capable of doing if they are given an explicit formula. They just want an explicit formula that produces a shape similar to what they've drawn. That is, the question isn't *really* about python or coding, but the abstract skill of matching formulas to graphs.

Comment: Why does (s)he mention Python in it? And not C++ or Basic? Is the purpose to  bragg about knowing Python?

Comment: Perhaps it is because Python is the only language he knows. We all start somewhere!

Comment: @markvs I'm glad they mentioned python, simply because it's the one piece of context that this question has. I at least now know the purpose of this question, and it gives me some idea of the "error tolerance" involved. I might have otherwise, based on the title, suggested that the OP try $(1 - x)^3$, or more likely, not suggested anything at all, because I'd have no idea how helpful it'd've been.

Comment: @SeanXie: Are you saying that it is possible to know only Python and nothing else?

Comment: @markvs I'm not sure dwelling over which language OP uses is helpful at this point. While it would be better if OP could comment to clarify their intentions as to whether they want a smooth function over the whole domain or breaking it into pieces would suffice, I feel it is sufficient to deduce that they intend to use some kind of graphing software to plot it, so an explicit formula that's easy to evaluate is needed. I don't think it's necessary to read further into the "in python" specification.

Comment: The question should be closed for lack of content or lack of details or both. I have voted to close.

Comment: @TheoBendit "the question isn't really about python or coding, but the abstract skill of matching formulas to graphs" Yes, thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

You want to craft $f(x)$ so that $f''(x)$ is

- positive for $0 < x < 1.$
- $= 0$, for $x = 1.$
- negative for $1 < x.$

Also, it appears that you want $f(0) = 0.$

Let $g(x) = f''(x)$.

It is easy to construct $g(x) = 1 - x.$

Then, integrating twice, you have that

$$ f(x) = \frac{x^2}{2} - \frac{x^3}{6}.\tag1 $$

**Edit**

If it is also desired that $f(1)$ take on a certain value $A$, note that in (1) above, you can add the term $rx^1$ to $f(x),$ where $r$ can be any scalar.  Such an added term will have no effect on either the second derivative of $f$, or the constraint that $f(0) = 0.$

**Edit**

In retrospect, given your question's preCalculus tag, I question how appropriate my answer is.  However, I was introduced to the concept of convex/concave functions as part of a Calculus class, and I do not know how to approach the problem in any other way.

Comment: The [tag:algebra-precalculus] tag was added by another editor. Originally, it was tagged [tag:algebraic-geometry] - take from that what you will.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: f(0)=A. Between 0 and 1 f(x) increasingly grows while it decreasing grows when x is greater than 1.

Answer (score 1):

python is able to concatenate functions, right, so why not use two functions, one for the each intervall?

Comment: Yes, it is a solution though one function might produce smoother graph.

Answer (score 1):

Consider

$$y=\arctan(x-1)+\pi/4$$
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! It has the most property that I need.

Comment: @Linghui of course, no prob